# Finite expansion of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I was doing finite expansion of an expression. What is the final answer of $\frac{x}{1+O(x^2)}$? Is it $O(x)$ or $x+O(x^3)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{x}{1+O(x^2)} = x(1+O(x^2)) = x + O(x^3).
$$

We get
$$
\frac{1}{1+O(x^2)} = 1+O(x^2)
$$

by considering the expansion $\frac{1}{1+x} = 1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + \dots$,

of course if it is understood that $x \rightarrow 0$. In general,

$$
\frac{1}{1+O(\phi(x))} = 1+O(\phi(x))
$$
so long as $\phi(x) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thank you, sir, I just wanted to be sure from that and you write enough. Do you have a good reference or another thing that can help in understanding how to working with these big O's?

Comment: You're welcome. For a good reference, see these lecture notes: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/595ama/

Comment: @AliWahhod don't forget to accept the answer if you please :)

Comment: Thank you sir :-)